# Everything is getting applied style on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using switchy http://lou.github.io/switchy/ and it uses animate-color.js

I have more than one, unlike their page, everytime one gets toogle all of them turn green, how can I prevent this so one gets toogle only

```
$(function() {

  $('.binary').switchy();

  $('.binary').on('change', function(){

    // Animate Switchy Bar background color 7cb15b
    var bgColor = '#ebebeb';

    if ($(this).val() == '1'){
      bgColor = '#7cb15b';
    } else if ($(this).val() == '0;'){
      bgColor = '#ebebeb';
    }
    $('.switchy-bar').animate({
      backgroundColor: bgColor
    });

    // Display action in console
    var log =  'Selected value is "'+$(this).val()+'"';
    $('#console').html(log).hide().fadeIn();
  });
});
```

You can see what I mean here www.niors.com

Answer (score 0):

`$('.switchy-bar')` affects all matching classes on the page. If you only want to change the one inside of the `.binary` class you have to search for it's child elements.

```
$(this).find('.switchy-bar').animate();
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are using the '.' selector.

I think you will need to select the individual switchy bar and change it's color.

```
var switchybar =  $(this).find('.switchy-bar');
if(switchybar !== undefined){
      switchybar.animate({
          backgroundColor: bgColor
       });

}
```

I hope it works for you.